# Which tool can I use to create automated tests for my own Desktop Browser application?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, desktop-application, sikuli-x

I'm seeking recommendations for a reliable testing tool suitable for testing my own desktop browser application. The application will be designed to run on both macOS and Windows operating systems.

I have previously experimented with SikuliX, but encountered stability issues that make it unsuitable for long-term testing. Specifically, I aim to write tests for fundamental browser functionalities such as URL searching, importing bookmarks, setting as default browser, and selecting search engines.

Any suggestions or insights into robust testing tools compatible with desktop browser applications on macOS and Windows would be greatly appreciated.

I tried automating it with sikulix but found it very unstable and having lot of bugs.
I need a tool which is stable enough and also possible to integrate with a CI tool for automated tests execution on a CI platform.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at BrowserStack? It is paid but it looks like it does what you need. You can visit their [website](https://browserstack.com/) to learn more about it.

Comment: I have already checked with BrowserStack but even though they do offer running tests in Browsers in the cloud, for my case they are not suitable as I want to run tests on my own custom browser application.